# How to bind by ElementName in Resources?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

It works, but not always.

1. Works.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseDown1">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="viewbox"
                     From="{Binding ElementName=viewbox, Path=ActualWidth}"
                     To="0"
                     Duration="0:0:1">
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseDown" SourceName="ellipse">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseDown1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Viewbox x:Name="viewbox">
    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red"></Ellipse>
</Viewbox></Window>
```

2. Works.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1></Window>
```

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseDown1">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="viewbox"
                         From="{Binding ElementName=viewbox, Path=ActualWidth}"
                         To="0"
                         Duration="0:0:1">
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Viewbox x:Name="viewbox">
    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red">
        <Ellipse.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseDown" SourceName="ellipse">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseDown1}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Ellipse.Triggers>
    </Ellipse>
</Viewbox></UserControl>
```

3. Doesn't work.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1></Window>
```

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseDown1">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="viewbox"
                         From="{Binding ElementName=viewbox, Path=ActualWidth}"
                         To="0"
                         Duration="0:0:1">
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseDown" SourceName="ellipse">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseDown1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
<Viewbox x:Name="viewbox">
    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red"></Ellipse>
</Viewbox></UserControl>
```

Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>   Additional information: Cannot animate the 'Width' property on a 'System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox' using a 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'. For details see the inner exception.

How to make it work?

Comment: what is in the inner exception?

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic I don't know how to check the inner exception. I tried, but failed to check it.

Comment: The inner exception should be `System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation cannot use default origin value of NaN`. Setting a Width to your viewbox should fix it.

Comment: @Elite026 Yes, but I need Width to be Auto. As mentioned in the examples, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.